# Azure DevOps Pipelines - PR trigger only run one stage, after complete continue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a `azure-pipelines.yaml` `Pipeline A` for my .NET Application with 3 stages.

> **Stage 1**: Restore, Build, Unit test, Publish artifact
>
> **Stage 2**: Consume artifact, build Docker image, push it to Artifact
> Repository
>
> **Stage 3**: Perform bash script

This works fine with normal Continuous Integration-trigger, but now I would like to add PR-trigger too.

Is it possible to ***only*** perform `Stage 1` (only restore, build, unit test, publish artifact) with PR then put it "on hold" ***until*** the PR is completed. And after completion, continue with `Stage 2` and consume the published artifact and continue build docker image etc?
Or am I better off setting up a completely new pipeline?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. However IMHO you don't need this. All what you need to do is to run first stage on PR trigger to validate state of your code. And then when it is merged to main branch, the CI trigger picks this up and runs all stages.

To limit first stage to just PR trigger you need to use this condition on stage level:

```
and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

Please add this to 2nd and 3rd stage.

Comment: This solution is neat, but gives me the price of running the first stage twice, once in the PR and once upon completion. In a worst case this could be very tedious and time consuming if the first stage has a long running job.
Should I instead split up stage 1 and stage2&stage3 into two separate pipelines?

Comment: Yes you are roght saying that first stage would be run twice. But please keep in mind that PR trigger runs on different branch than CI. What would be if in the meantime someone else commit changes to the main branch? You will use outdated version.